# LogMeIn Rescue won't work with Firefox 43+

Tags: firefox-extensions, logmein

Installing the LogMeIn extension to Firefox version 43 and above results in an error.  So I cannot create a session in order to connect with a customer.

Answer (score 0):

When Firefox went from version 42 to 43+, they required extensions to be signed.  As of today (Feb 2017), LogMeIn has not signed the extension.  LogMeIn also does not support Chrome.

Answer (for now): The only thing we can do is downgrade to Firefox 42 and turn off updates.

Answer (for future): Move from the web browser product to the stand-alone Windows product.